# jquery datatable in visual studio plugin not working

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, datatables

Hey im trying to make a jquery datatable in visual studio 2019 for my code but the datatable wont show up i have installed "Install-Package bootbox" and "Install-Package jQuery.DataTables" successfully but when i run the code the datatable does not show up. I have looked all over the web could not find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:When i do right click on the project "Inspect" gives me this error:

```
jquery.dataTables.js:1197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1197)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.js:367)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.js:202)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1194)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.js:367)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.js:202)
    at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15172)
    at Index:153
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace AuditoriskaMVC1
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootbox.js",
                      "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js",
                      "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"
                    ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
@model IEnumerable<AuditoriskaMVC1.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table" id="moviesTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DownloadURL)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImagedURL)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
            </th>
        
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@item.DownloadURL">Download Here!</a>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <img style="max-width:200px" src="@item.ImagedURL" />

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section  scripts{
     <script>
         $("#moviesTable").DataTable();
     </script>   
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out but just in case anyone else has this problem im gonna leave this post up.

The solution is that the table head and table body need to have the same amount of

in this case the table head has 1 less  so even tho you are not getting any errors for some reason in Visual Studio there is one in the background and u can only see it if you right click and Inspect your page. The fix is just add an empty  if u have less of them in either the head or body.

Comment: The sane amount of what, sorry?